# Use Javascript to click tricky Select HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to click around using Javascript in the Console (Chrome) on a [Kelley Blue Book page](https://www.kbb.com/car-prices/), but am getting stuck on the first select element, the "make" dropdown. The end goal is to select a make and model then hit the next button.

Here is what the HTML looks like (took out some of the options):

```
    <div class="make">
         <div class="css-k9vu0d-SelectWrapper-body-VehiclePickerInput e1019m8z0" id="">
               <select class="css-1qn61q8-StyledHiddenSelect e1euwze60">
                        <option selected="" value="" disabled="">BMW</option><option value="Acura">Acura</option>
                        <option value="Alfa Romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
                        <option value="Aston Martin">Aston Martin</option> 
                </select>
          <div width="auto" tabindex="-1" class="css-7kga7i-StyledSelect efry5w70">
            <div class="css-19v4425-MainDisplay efry5w71">
            <div class="css-erfxdy-ValueDisplay efry5w72">
                 <div class="css-1fx1pq8-EmptyPlaceholder efry5w75">Make</div></div>
                 <div class="css-196vjd2-Carot efry5w78">
          <div class="css-armdrj-StyledDropdownMenu eq7efy70">
                <div disabled="" class="css-crz4ue-StyledOption eq7efy71">Make</div>
                <div data-value="Acura" class="css-u49v6v-StyledOption eq7efy71">Acura</div>
                <div data-value="Alfa Romeo" class="css-u49v6v-StyledOption eq7efy71">Alfa Romeo</div>
                <div data-value="Aston Martin" class="css-u49v6v-StyledOption eq7efy71">Aston Martin</div>
```

I have tried the following JS commands,

click div with class:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('css-k9vu0d-SelectWrapper-body-VehiclePickerInput e1019m8z0')[0].click()
```

click div with class:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('css-1qn61q8-StyledHiddenSelect e1euwze60')[0].click()
```

set select element value:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('css-1qn61q8-StyledHiddenSelect e1euwze60')[0].selectedIndex = 6
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

For starters, please include a [mcve] to your question. Otherwise, it might take a lot more time and a heap of guessing to figure *exactly* where the issue lies.

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot** "open" a `select` element by programmatically clicking it.

**You can** set the value of a select programmatically.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.css-1qn61q8-StyledHiddenSelect.e1euwze60');

select.value = "Alfa Romeo";
```

```html
<select class="css-1qn61q8-StyledHiddenSelect e1euwze60">
  <option selected="" value="" disabled="">BMW</option>
  <option value="Acura">Acura</option>
  <option value="Alfa Romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
  <option value="Aston Martin">Aston Martin</option>
</select>
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName can handle multiple class names.  It's true programmatically click on select element won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your code. What actually shows in the select element on the page doesn't change. It still says "Make".

If I ask for the value it in the console it says "Alfa Romeo" however. What is going on here?

Comment: @lhoro Thanks for the heads up. Wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @Branden Seeing the class name part `StyledHiddenSelect` on it, I assume what you are seeing in the browser is no longer the native `select` element. Try to inspect it using the developer tools of your browser. It seems your page has some Javascript that hides the native select element (most sites do this because they cannot accept the non-styleability of the native select element) and instead puts a replacement structure in place that only *looks* like a select element.